# FETCHING DATA WITH AXIOS RETURNING UNDEFINED THEN DATA IN REACT

Tags: reactjs, nodes

This is my full component, and when I console log, I get undefined before getting some objects, how can I fix this?

```
    import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const ProductScreen = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const [products1, setProducts1] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${params.id}`);
      setProducts1(data);
      return products1;
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, [params.id]);
console.log(products1);
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

When I console log i get an empty array then my object

```
[]
{
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "Azus Vivobook Flip",
    "category": "laptop",
    "price": 600,
    "rating": "4.3",
    "image": "/images/Vivobookflip.jpg"
}
```

Comment: why are you returning `products1` from `fetchProducts`? It's not necessary. And what are you logging? which and where. If you are logging directly at the start then it will be undefined as `useEffect` is an side effect i.e. after component is mounted then it will execute.

Comment: Got you, I was returning because I saw that I had to return something. So I am building an ecommerce website and I want to make a single product page where I can display information about every product. This should return the product which has the id in the URL that I am fetching from. But it works sometimes and sometimes it gives back undefined

Comment: Let me add the whole code to give you an idea

Comment: where is your console.log?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: since your function is async it won't have completed until after the first render so the first time you do `console.log(products1);` you should get `[]` which is your initial state

Comment: It's exactly as I stated as it's in `useEffect` then it will be executed after it mounted for the first time/rendered so at first it's an `[]` and then `useEffect` will be triggered and then it will update `products1` and again rerender and hence it got logged for the 2nd time.

Comment: Yes that's what I have noticed, is there any way I can get around this problem? Like only display when useEffect is triggered?

Comment: If you do something like   `const [products1, setProducts1] = useState(undefined);` and then do `if (products1 === undefined) return null` it won't add anything to the page until `products1` has a value. Instead of a `null` you can also show a loading icon if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

if you use

> "proxy": "http://yourlink.com"

than you should check front end console

Comment: I used that, And when I check in the console I get undefined then my object.